# How rendering is done in Airplay Mirroring?

Tags: airplay

I have a question regarding Apple's Airplay mirroring technology where one device hosts a game, and other devices can join that game.

One of the new features of Airplay Mirroring is the ability to use your HD TV to show a split screen of the game (see pic http://cdn.gamerant.com/wp-content/uploads/Real-Racing-2-to-Add-Multiplayer-Party-Play-Using-AirPlay.jpg).

My question is does the host device do all the rendering job for all players and then streams images to all of the other devices? I'm asking this because the game above ONLY requires the host device to be Airplay-enbled in order to use the split screen feature (other devices that join the game can be any airplay-compatible devices), so it seems to me that it's the only one that is capable of streaming to the HD TV?

You can check the requirements of the game here http://firemint.com/2011/guide-to-setting-up-airplay-and-party-play/

Thanks

Comment: I don't think "other devices can join the game". Airplay Mirroring is just video streaming, right? The game really exists only on the host device, and if it has multiplayer support somehow this will be handled on that device and by that application (not by Airplay).

Comment: Well, according to the game instructions above, all of the devices have to have the game where one device hosts the game and other devices join the game.

Comment: Yes, and Airplay Mirroring has nothing to do with that. It just streams the "Party View" from the host device to the TV. I would assume that the other devices render their own view themselves.